# Phrases interrogatives : préposition + quoi/qui ... ?

Tags: grammaire, questions, interrogative

Je sais qu'il est correct de dire:

> **À quoi/qui** est-ce que tu penses ?
>
> **À quoi/qui** penses-tu ?
>
> Tu penses **à quoi/qui** ?

ou

> **À quoi/qui** est-ce que ta mère pense ?
>
> **À quoi/qui** ta mère pense-t-elle ?
>
> **À quoi/qui** pense ta mère ?
>
> Ta mère pense **à quoi/qui** ?

Mais je n'en suis pas sûr en ce qui concerne les formulations suivantes :

> **À quoi/qui** tu penses ?
>
> **À quoi/qui** ta mère pense ?

Est-ce que les deux formulations sont grammaticalement correctes ? Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est plus une question d'usage que de syntaxe :
"A quoi tu penses?"  est utilisé.
"A quoi ta mère pense ?" ne l'est pas.

"A quoi ta mère pense" représente plutôt la chose, celle à laquelle elle pense.
Pour en faire une question, il faut poser cette question :
"A quoi ta mère pense-**t-elle ?**"
"A quoi **elle** pense, ta mère ?"  ou " **Elle** pense à quoi, ta mère ?"
ou alors: "**sais-tu** à quoi ta mère pense ?"

Answer (score 2):

*Tu penses à quoi ?* and *À quoi tu penses ?* are both common idiomatic spoken French. The former is more relaxed.

*À quoi est-ce que tu penses ?* is standard French.

*À quoi penses-tu ?* is formal

Same for the *à qui* and *ta mère* variants.